# How can i get equal date values when saving,and then get this value from entity field?

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc

I am not able to solve a specific problem with date format in my class repository.
These are the two methods with which I have this situation.

```
import java.util.Date;

//my local variabble
 private Date bonusStartDate;

 //My methods to get and set this variable
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @Column(name = "bonus_start_date")
    public Date getBonusStartDate() {
        return bonusStartDate;
    }

    public void setBonusStartDate(Date bonusStartDate) {
        this.bonusStartDate = bonusStartDate;
    }
```

I insert the value in entity field with `java.util.Object`.
 If I try to get the date value, the method getBonusStartDate() returns a timestamp.
 I want to save this value `Tue Jul 05 13:35:19 EEST 2016`, and the value I get from the field is  `2016-07-05 13:35:19.000`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I solve my question with this :

long d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 60 * 1000).getTime();
bonus.setStartDate(new Date((d / 1000) * 1000));

Comment: This annotations,dose not work with Hibernate and real data base,only with in memory :

 @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)